# Wordpress Recent Post with the badge "New" on the side of the title post

Tags: html, css, wordpress, function

[image]

[image]

I'd like to greet everyone a Happy New Year and Happy Holidays. I have a request on how to put a label "New" beside the title post on my recent post and my single recent post(red Mark in the photo). I keep on finding for answers on the internet for days and I couldn't find one. I hope you guys give an idea, demo or answers on this particular wordpress subject this would give me a big help and I hope I didn't bother anyone on celebrating your holiday. Thank you.

Comment: Might be better suited for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andrey Noted I'm gonna put it there right away thank you for brought this one up to me.

Comment: I'm missing your clarification when a post is 'new'. Is this just the first post, or 'x amount of days/hours'. The last time you visited the page. etc. Could you be more specific when a post needs this label?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink "New" will trigger once you have a recent new post on the blog page

Comment: @ArnoTenkink I just got it it suppose to be a "badge" beside the title post for the recent post

Comment: I get what you want it to look like, and it's for 'new posts'. But it's *important* to know *what* is a new post? Is it only for the most recent post or can there be multiple new posts, posted within for example 2 or 3 days.

Comment: @ArnoTenkink yes the new post supposed to be posted within 1 or 2 days.